# Integral with boundary functions

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

I need to find the integral

$$F(x) = \int_0^x \frac{t+1+|t-1|}{2} dt $$

I tried take $x>0$ and $x<0$ as:

$F(x) = \int_0^x \frac{t+1+|t-1|}{2} dt $ = $  \int_0^x \frac{t+1+(t-1)}{2} dt$ + $  \int_0^x \frac{t+1-(t-1)}{2} dt$ =  $\int_0^x tdt$ +  $\int_0^x  dt$ = $ \frac{x^2}{2} + x$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What matters is when $x\gt 1$ or $x\leq 1$

If $x\leq 1$, $|t-1|=1-t$ and $F(x)=x$

If $x\gt 1$,

$$F(x)=\int_0^1dt+\int_1^xtdt={x^2\over 2}+{1\over 2}$$